# What should one pay attention to when translating "I will go to military-school [within the next week]" into Chinese?

Tags: translation, grammar, syntax, adverbs

What advice for translation could you give in this context,
how would you translate the following sentences containing adverbials:

1. I will go to military-school **soon.**
2. I will go to military-school **within the next week**.
3. I will go to military-school **once I have finished studying**.

My attempt on translating (please feel free to correct my mistakes):

- 我 **即将** 去 军校。
- 我 **下星期里** 去 军校。
- 我 **比及读完** 去 军校

Comment: some people might suggest 一旦我读完了书我将去军校 for 3

Comment: I think they are all the same meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`我即将去军校` is grammatically correct, but `即将` sounds too formal. Try this:

> 我很快就要去军校了。 I soon will go-to  military-school le.

Notice that I used `了` which marks the end of what I am saying. Otherwise a listener may expect that you have something more to say. There are subtle uses of `了` that may take pages to explain.

If you want a formal form, `我即将去军校了` is perfectly fine.

---

`我下星期里去军校` is understandable. `Within` is kind of a formal preposition word in English. In Chinese you may want to say:

> 我要在下星期内去军校。 I will at next week within go-to military-school.

`在...(以)内` is more idiomatic.

---

`我比及读完去军校` -- `比及` is an archaic word that is no longer in use. `study` is `学习`; It can be `读` sometimes, but the context is missing. Anyway:

> 我一旦学习完就去军校。 I once study finish then go-to military-school.

Answer (score 1):

I will go to military-school soon.
我很快就要去军校了。

I will go to military-school within the next week. (Sounds a bit strange)
I will go to military-school within a week.
我将在一周内去军校上课。

I will go to military-school once I have finished studying.
(If you are going on to military school, you haven't finished studying!)
After I graduate, I will go the military academy to continue my studies.
等我毕业之后，我会去军校继续学习。